# ActiveRecord "IOError: could not reopen: null"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jruby

I just experienced my app having errors on every page load or almost every page load. A restart cleared out all the problems. Here is what I think happened.

The first error, was "IOError: could not reopen: null"

```
"org/jruby/RubyIO.java" line 501 in reopen
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 52 in silence_stream
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 109 in quietly
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 50 in silence_stream
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 108 in quietly
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb" line 64 in get_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb" line 266 in load_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb" line 43 in load_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb" line 51 in stale_session_check!
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb" line 43 in load_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb" line 168 in load!
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb" line 160 in load_for_read!
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/request/session.rb" line 86 in []
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/session_serializer.rb" line 30 in fetch
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb" line 212 in user
...
```

There was only one of those. Then, on every page request, i get "Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor"

```
"org/jruby/RubyIO.java" line 2097 in close
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 53 in silence_stream
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 109 in quietly
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 50 in silence_stream
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb" line 108 in quietly
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-session_store-0.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/session/active_record_store.rb" line 64 in get_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb" line 266 in load_session
"/app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb" line 43 in load_session
...
```

What cause the initial problem?

Comment: where is code sir ? :-)

Comment: thanks for the qeustion. the thing is, the issue is clearly something to do with the activerecord connection at a low level.. i showed the top of the stack tracer. the first stack trace didn't include any application code, the second one has different app lines for each instance (whenever it happens to ask for the database first)

Comment: are you sure your connection parameters are correct

Comment: yes -- the app has been running for months with no problem, and a restart of the app cleared this problem and it hasn't returned.

Answer (score 1):

weird stuff such as these are likely caused by Rails not being "absolutely" thread-safe (even on MRI but it's more obvious on JRuby since it's "GIL-free") ... `Rails.logger.silence` and related have not been 100% thread-safe https://gist.github.com/kares/9374772 I've dealt with similar issues (on JRuby on Rails) since 2.3 and there sure were attempts to fix this but somehow the same silencing logic keeps getting back.

the whole `silence_stream(STDOUT) {}` code (that your trace reveals), I would guess, might end up in a similar "unpredictable" state. I would try patching **kernel/reporting.rb** so that the stream silencers do nothing (I've updated the gist as well).

Comment: thanks for a thorough answer that clearly took you a lot of pain to discover yourself! -- it's not clear to me if the first and second part of the gist are required for my problem, and why the "simple" alternative isn't what you recommend. could you move that code into your SO answer and make it more clear? thanks!

Comment: I actually prefer to leave "non-trivial" code such as this one in a gist so that users potentially see changes/forks. for gem version 0.1.0 [due](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store/commit/cf317939c3df3195ececb938c27fbccc8e228ba2) you'll need the second part. if I were you I would put in both parts to avoid "similar" future issues with not having log entries.

Comment: kares, thank you for your invaluable input, but the thing is i don't feel that the solution has been explained thoroughly enough for me to feel confident just throwing this huge monkeypatch into my production application. for example your gist says "the final frontier is ActiveRecord::Base.silence (2.3 - 3.2)" -- what does this mean, this code is only necessary for rails < 3.2? why is that the "final" frontier?

Comment: John, just go through the code in various versions of AR if you're trying to understand things in absolute detail - the idea is very simple to avoid all "silencers" ... `AR::Base.silence` only exists in those versions (removed in 4.0 which you can easily find out looking up Rails sources) ... maybe I'll remove the comments so that there's only code, would probably be clearer :) !